# Managing User Settings

Tags: vba, ms-access

I created a MS Access front end that utilizes specific file locations. I originally created this as a tool for myself to be the only user. Since I sometimes work on it at home, I needed it to be able to detect if I was using it at home or on my work computer because the file locations are different. So, I created a table “tblSettings” and load the settings (based on which computer I’m using) when my Access FE opens.

In a module, I declare:

```
    Public Const conHOME_ENVIRON = "{Me on Home Computer Name}"
    Public Const conWORK_ENVIRON = "{Me on Work Computer Name}"
```

I then set a global string variable when my Startup form loads:

```
    gstrUserComputer = VBA.Environ("USERNAME") & " on " & VBA.Environ("USERDOMAIN")
```

Throughout my code, I’ll use something like:

```
    If gstrUserComputer = conWORK_ENVIRON then
       Do stuff at work
    ElseIf gstrUserComputer = conHOME_ENVIRON then
       Do stuff at home
    Else
       Do other stuff
    End if
```

All this works just fine (I know my computer’s names), but now I need to share this front end with other users at work and I don’t know how to manage the other users in my front end (I don't know their computer names). I want to make it so “ANY” user can use this app and set their own settings.

Is there a  better way to manage users settings and how should I go about it? Please keep it as simple to understand as possible since I’m a novice at this. Sample code would be a big help.

Thanks in advance for your help. I am using Access for MS 365 if that matters.

Comment: Why not have a table in the DB where user settings are stored by using Environ USERNAME as the Key, save/retrieve settings from the table WHERE KeyField = USERNAME. Else you can create Default settings and store them outside the DB on a temp file, check for the file, if exists, load settings, if not, load default. If settings change, write/overrite Temp settings file.

Comment: `VBA.Environ("computername")` returns the computer name.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the computer name, user logon with this:

```
dim strcomputerName as string
strComputerName = Environ("computername")
```

and to get the current windows logon name, you can use:

```
dim strWindowsUser as string
strWindowsUser  = Environ("USERNAME")
```

So, you don't need nor want to use a "constant", but on startup you can use above to get the name - thus not hard coded.

So either always use some pubic function name, or on startup setup some global variables. Using function names is probably better if you use a accDB. But, if you always send users a compiled accDE, then global variables will never re-set - even with unhandled errors. but, global vars in a accDB? They can and will get re-set for un-handled errors. For this reason, often sending and disribution your code compiled as accDE has advantages.

But, perhaps you don't bother with a constant, and just create two public functions in a standard code module.

say like:

```
 Public Function GetUser() as string
   GetUser = Environ("USERNAME")
 End function

Public Function GetComputerName as string
    GetComputerName = Environ("computername")
End Function
```

So, now you can use the above two functions anywhere in code.